# If $\cos\theta = \frac{1} {2}\left(e^{i\theta} +e^{-i\theta}\right)$ Find an expression for $\arccos\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I need some help on this one.

If $\cos\theta = \frac{1} {2}\left(e^{i\theta} +e^{-i\theta}\right)$   Find an expression for $\arccos\theta$

Comment: Hint: Write it as $x = \frac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}{2}$, and substitute in $u = e^{iy}$.  Once you clear denominators you'll have a quadratic in $u$.  Solve it, and then substitute back in for $y$.

Comment: Polar Coordinates but ended with an ugly expression.

Answer (score 4):

$z=\cos \theta=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$. Solve now for $\theta$, let $v=e^{i\theta}$ then: $v+\frac{1}{v}=2z$, $v=z+\sqrt{z^2-1}$ Finally: 
$$\theta=\arccos z=\frac{1}{i}\ln\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** By Euler's beautiful identity,
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
so by substitution,
$$\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta+\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta))$$
Now use the fact that $\sin$ is odd and $\cos$ is even to get
$$\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta+\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)$$
Do you see what to do now?